# Testing a file in a tar archive

Tags: linux, bash, file, tar

I've been manipulating a tar file and I would like to test if a file exists before extracting it

Let's say I have an tar file called Archive.Tar and after entering

```
tar -tvf Archive.Tar
```

I get:

```
-rwxrwxrwx guy/root          1502 2013-10-02 20:43 Directory/File
-rwxrwxrwx guy/root           494 2013-10-02 20:43 Dir/SubDir/Text
drwxrwxrwx guy/root             0 2013-10-02 20:43 Directory
```

I want to extract Text into my Working directory, but I want to be sure that it's actually a file by doing this:

```
if [ -f Dir/Sub/Text ]
then
    echo "OK"
else
    echo "KO"
fi
```

The result of this test is always `KO` and I really don't understand why, any suggestions?

Comment: How are you testing this "before extracting it"? That is, what is `Dir/Sub/Text` if you have not extracted anything? It's unclear what your exact sequence of steps are.

Comment: In a script I'm writing I must test that said `Dir/Sub/Text` is a file before extracting it with `tar -xvf Archive.tar Dir/Sub/Text` , sorry for not being explicit enough

Comment: I know that is what you have to do. But how do you expect the script you have shown to work since `-f` tests a path? You can't test a path that does not exist (since you have not extracted it).

Comment: That's my problem! The only thing I have in mind is extracting it first and then testing if it's a file. Since I'm actually working with a lot of files, I'll then delete those that aren't files from the working directory.

Comment: Are you trying to determine if it's a file instead of a directory, or just determine if it exists in the archive?  I suspect the latter, in which case you just need to specify it. `tar -xf Archive.Tar Dir/Sub/Text` will extract only `Dir/Sub/Text` or fail and emit a nice error message if `Dir/Sub/Text` is not in the archive.

Answer (score 0):

Tested with BSD and GNU versions of tar,
in the output of `tar tf`,
entries that are directories end with `/`.
So to test if `Dir/Sub/Text` is a file or directory in the archive,
you can simply grep with full line matching:

```
if tar tf Archive.Tar | grep -x Dir/Sub/Text >/dev/null
then
    echo "OK"
else
    echo "KO"
fi
```

If the archive contains `Dir/SubDir/Text/`, then `Dir/SubDir/Text` is a directory, and the `grep` will not match, so KO will be printed.

If the archive contains `Dir/SubDir/Text` without a trailing `/`,
then `Dir/SubDir/Text` is a file and the `grep` will match,
so OK will be printed.

Answer (score 0):

```
if [ ! -d Dir/Sub/Text ]
then
    echo "OK"
else
    echo "KO"
fi
```

will return KO only if a directory Text exists and be ok if it's a file or does not exist (or to be precise also OK if it would be a symlink).

Answer (score -1):

This might be a solution,

```
tar -tvf Archive.Tar | grep Dir/Sub/Text
```

This will let you know if it find the file.

Comment: How does that tell you it is a file and not a directory?